# How can I use date in Airbnb daterange without time - just date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using airbnb daterange picker in react.

```
<DateRangePicker
    startDate={this.state.startDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
    startDateId="your_unique_start_date_id" // PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    endDate={this.state.endDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
    endDateId="your_unique_end_date_id" // PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) => {
      this.setState({ startDate, endDate });

    }} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} // PropTypes.oneOf([START_DATE, END_DATE]) or null,
    onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    daySize={50}
    noBorder={true}
    isOutsideRange={() => false}
  />
```

When I select a date I receive a date with time part also, for example :

If I select 26 June I'm getting :

```
{26/06/2019 12:00:00}
```

So how could I get only {26/06/2019 00:00:00}

Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: When you ASKING about libraries, try adding a sandbox of your code, https://codesandbox.io/s/new. Moreover, your question related to matching a string (if its a string), read about `Regular Expressions`.

Comment: momentjs has a [set](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/) functionality, you could just set them to 0

Answer (score 0):

Your question not related to React.

I'm guessing that in writing `{26/06/2019 12:00:00}` you meant for a string: `"26/06/2019 12:00:00"` or for [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instance:

```js
const endDateString = "26/06/2019 12:00:00";

const dateRegex = /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/g

const dateString = endDateString.match(dateRegex);

console.log(endDateString); // ["26/06/2019"]

const endDate = new Date('June 26, 2019 12:00:00');

const fromInstance = `${endDate.getDate()}/${endDate.getMonth()}/${endDate.getFullYear()}`

console.log(fromInstance);
```